# How to get face_detection_ex.cpp in dlib to work in c++?

Tags: c++, cmake, clion, dlib

I'm new to c++, so sorry if there is an obvious solution I'm missing.  I'm trying to run [this](https://github.com/davisking/dlib/blob/master/examples/face_detection_ex.cpp) example code for dlib in c++.  I'm getting this error...

```
In file included from /Users/john/ClionProjects/dlib/examples/face_detection_ex.cpp:41:
In file included from /Users/john/ClionProjects/dlib/dlib/../dlib/gui_widgets.h:13:
In file included from /Users/john/ClionProjects/dlib/dlib/../dlib/image_processing/../gui_widgets/widgets.h:9:
In file included from /Users/john/ClionProjects/dlib/dlib/../dlib/image_processing/../gui_widgets/drawable.h:8:
In file included from /Users/john/ClionProjects/dlib/dlib/../dlib/image_processing/../gui_widgets/../gui_core.h:14:
In file included from /Users/john/ClionProjects/dlib/dlib/../dlib/image_processing/../gui_core/xlib.h:4:
/Users/john/ClionProjects/dlib/dlib/../dlib/image_processing/../gui_core/gui_core_kernel_2.h:11:2: error: "DLIB_NO_GUI_SUPPORT is defined so you can't use the GUI code.  Turn DLIB_NO_GUI_SUPPORT off if you want to use it."
#error "DLIB_NO_GUI_SUPPORT is defined so you can't use the GUI code.  Turn DLIB_NO_GUI_SUPPORT off if you want to use it."
 ^
/Users/johnoberhauser/ClionProjects/dlib/dlib/../dlib/image_processing/../gui_core/gui_core_kernel_2.h:12:2: error: "Also make sure you have libx11-dev installed on your system"
#error "Also make sure you have libx11-dev installed on your system"
```

I've tried going into /dlib/CMakeLists.txt and adding

```
set(DLIB_NO_GUI_SUPPORT OFF)
```

I know it's found the X11 package as I'm not getting a message from the cmake there (and I just installed XQuartz)

Also, I'm using Clion, so I'm not running cmake from the command line.  And I'm on OSX

**Edit**: I tried removing the parts of the code that use the gui, just to see if it would work.  But I then get this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_USER_ERROR__missing_dlib_all_source_cpp_file__OR__inconsistent_use_of_DEBUG_or_ENABLE_ASSERTS_preprocessor_directives", referenced from:
  _dlib_check_consistent_assert_usage in main.cpp.o
  "_cblas_saxpy", referenced from:
  dlib::blas_bindings::cblas_axpy(int, float, float const*, int, float*, int) in main.cpp.o
  "_cblas_sscal", referenced from:
  dlib::blas_bindings::cblas_scal(int, float, float*) in main.cpp.o
  "_dgesvd_", referenced from:
  dlib::lapack::binding::gesvd(char, char, int, int, double*, int, double*, double*, int, double*, int, double*, int) in main.cpp.o
  "_png_create_info_struct", referenced from:
  dlib::png_loader::read_image(char const*) in libdlib.a(png_loader.cpp.o)
  "_png_create_read_struct", referenced from:
  dlib::png_loader::read_image(char const*) in libdlib.a(png_loader.cpp.o)
  "_png_destroy_read_struct", referenced from:
  dlib::png_loader::read_image(char const*) in libdlib.a(png_loader.cpp.o)
  dlib::png_loader::~png_loader() in libdlib.a(png_loader.cpp.o)
  dlib::png_loader::~png_loader() in libdlib.a(png_loader.cpp.o)
  "_png_get_bit_depth", referenced from:
  dlib::png_loader::read_image(char const*) in libdlib.a(png_loader.cpp.o)
  "_png_get_color_type", referenced from:
  dlib::png_loader::read_image(char const*) in libdlib.a(png_loader.cpp.o)
  "_png_get_image_height", referenced from:
  dlib::png_loader::read_image(char const*) in libdlib.a(png_loader.cpp.o)
  "_png_get_image_width", referenced from:
  dlib::png_loader::read_image(char const*) in libdlib.a(png_loader.cpp.o)
  "_png_get_rows", referenced from:
  dlib::png_loader::read_image(char const*) in libdlib.a(png_loader.cpp.o)
  "_png_init_io", referenced from:
  dlib::png_loader::read_image(char const*) in libdlib.a(png_loader.cpp.o)
  "_png_read_png", referenced from:
  dlib::png_loader::read_image(char const*) in libdlib.a(png_loader.cpp.o)
  "_png_set_longjmp_fn", referenced from:
  dlib::png_loader::read_image(char const*) in libdlib.a(png_loader.cpp.o)
  dlib::png_loader_user_error_fn_silent(png_struct_def*, char const*) in libdlib.a(png_loader.cpp.o)
  "_png_set_palette_to_rgb", referenced from:
  dlib::png_loader::read_image(char const*) in libdlib.a(png_loader.cpp.o)
  "_png_set_sig_bytes", referenced from:
  dlib::png_loader::read_image(char const*) in libdlib.a(png_loader.cpp.o)
  "_png_sig_cmp", referenced from:
  dlib::png_loader::read_image(char const*) in libdlib.a(png_loader.cpp.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

I think this is a separate issue from the first one, but idk, maybe they are related?  For this issue, I've tried doing what was mentioned here https://github.com/davisking/dlib/issues/57   I made the link for the first part, then added these lines to my cmakelist.txt

```
include_directories(../../../../usr/X11/lib)
include_directories(../../../../usr/local/include)
include_directories(../../../../usr/local/lib)
```

Didn't seem to fix the issue though.

**Edit 2:**  So I think both these issues are resolved now.  I think added those include_directories lines that I mentioned above help.  Also, I started using cmake from the command line, instead of with clion.

However, I am now getting a new error :/

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "dlib::base_window::invalidate_rectangle(dlib::rectangle const&)", referenced from:
  void dlib::image_display::set_image<dlib::array2d<unsigned char, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > >(dlib::array2d<unsigned char, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > const&) in main.cpp.o
  "dlib::base_window::set_size(int, int)", referenced from:
  void dlib::image_window::set_image<dlib::array2d<unsigned char, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > >(dlib::array2d<unsigned char, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > const&) in main.cpp.o
     "dlib::image_window::add_overlay(std::__1::vector<dlib::image_display::overlay_rect, std::__1::allocator<dlib::image_display::overlay_rect> > const&)", referenced from:
  void dlib::image_window::add_overlay<dlib::rgb_pixel>(std::__1::vector<dlib::rectangle, std::__1::allocator<dlib::rectangle> > const&, dlib::rgb_pixel) in main.cpp.o
  "dlib::image_window::clear_overlay()", referenced from:
  _main in main.cpp.o
  "dlib::image_window::image_window()", referenced from:
  _main in main.cpp.o
  "dlib::image_window::~image_window()", referenced from:
  _main in main.cpp.o
  "dlib::popup_menu_region::disable()", referenced from:
  void dlib::image_display::set_image<dlib::array2d<unsigned char, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > >(dlib::array2d<unsigned char, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > const&) in main.cpp.o
  "dlib::scrollable_region::set_total_rect_size(unsigned long, unsigned long)", referenced from:
  void dlib::image_display::set_image<dlib::array2d<unsigned char, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > >(dlib::array2d<unsigned char, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > const&) in main.cpp.o
  "dlib::draw_sunken_rectangle(dlib::canvas const&, dlib::rectangle const&, unsigned char)", referenced from:
      dlib::scrollable_region_style_default::draw_scrollable_region_border(dlib::canvas const&, dlib::rectangle const&, bool) const in main.cpp.o
  "dlib::image_display::get_image_display_rect() const", referenced from:
  void dlib::image_window::set_image<dlib::array2d<unsigned char, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > >(dlib::array2d<unsigned char, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > const&) in main.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

One issue after another :/

**Edit 3:**  Success!  So I was using Clion for compiling.  Even though the cmake from clion is the same version as the cmake I'm using in the command line, it just didn't work for some reason.

Comment: dlib_face_detection_ex needs to have GUI, so you need to compile dlib with GUI support and remove set(DLIB_NO_GUI_SUPPORT OFF)
can you run any other samples?

Comment: I've removed the set(DLIB_NO_GUI_SUPPORT OFF), but it still doesn't work.  Some other examples do work, but they don't use the gui.  I tried commenting out  include "dlib/gui_widgets.h" which is what uses the gui and removing the code related to it.  (I think all it does is show a window with an image that has an overlay showing where the face is).  I don't get this error when that happens, although I get a new error.  I'll update my question with that error.

Comment: How did you get dlib up in xcode?
I am getting some errors 

`_USER_ERROR__missing_dlib_all_source_cpp_file__OR__inconsistent_use_of_DEBUG_or_ENABLE_ASSERTS_preprocessor_directives_", referenced from:`

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by **deleting the "cmake-build-debug" directory**.

Then reopen the project(CLion will regenerate it).

It seems there remain some cache files would affect the compiling.

---

But before this step, please make sure you do install XQuartz.